# tkinter Python3 keep label value after button click, on next application start

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

**Scenario**:
I have a button and a label on my canvas.
When I load the application I have my label text set to **Not Pressed**
I also have a button that is tied to the **oks** command variable I created to set the label value to **Pressed** when the button is clicked.
here is my code snippet

```
def oks():
    lblff.config(text="Pressed")    

lblff = ttk.Label(tbwebman, text='Not Pressed')
btnff = ttk.Button(tbwebman,image = icoff,cursor="fleur", command=oks)
```

This works, I understand that when I exit the application the label text will be **Not Pressed** the next time I load it.

My goal is,  I want to keep the label value to **Pressed** the next time the application is ran.

This leads to my question, to reach my goal should I save the value in an external data source, for example a text file, or is there a way to save the value internally in the python script?

Comment: You have to save it in an external file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store the value internally in the python script.
You can open the python script when it is running and then write ' x = "pressed" 'so next time the script is opened there is variable which has the value from the previous runtime. Something like this:

```
def oks():
    lblff.config(text="Pressed") 
    with open("__file__","w+") as write_file:
       code = write_file.read() 
       write_file.write("x = 'pressed' \n"+code)

lblff = ttk.Label(tbwebman, text='Not Pressed')
btnff = ttk.Button(tbwebman,image = icoff,cursor="fleur", command=oks)
```

But I really do not recommend doing this, it is best practice to open a new file instead.

Comment: Instead of `"the path to the running python script"` use `__file__`. It should be defined to the current file that's running. Also what does the `add_varibale` store? Also also why not store it in a file and then just read the file and use an `if` statement on the program start-up.